# Can't map date correctly with elasticsearch + kibana + twitter

Tags: elasticsearch, twitter

I am trying to stream twitter to elasticsearch.
I am having no problems if i do not create any index before streaming, but in such a way i can't filter by date and create timelines.
I tried to use this mapping:

https://gist.github.com/christinabo/ca99793a5d160fe12fd9a31827e74444

that allegedly allows for "date" to be correctly picked by ES, but i receive this error when creating the index:

"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "unknown setting [index.twitter.mappings._doc.properties.coordinates.properties.coordinates.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"

what's wrong?

thanks

Comment: How are you sending the Request? cURL, postman, kibana, other?

Comment: How is your request? It seems to be malformed since it is confusing your mapping with index settings.

Answer (score 0):

I am running this python script. Before, I have tried to set the mapping from Dev Tools with PUT twitter_stream. Sorry for the terrible indentation!

```
    es = Elasticsearch("https://admin:admin@localhost:9200", 
    verify_certs=False)
    es.indices.create(index='twitter_stream', ignore=400)

    class StreamApi(tweepy.StreamListener):
    status_wrapper = TextWrapper(width=60, initial_indent='    ', 
   subsequent_indent='    ')

    def on_status(self, status):

  json_data = status._json

   es.index(index="twitter_stream",
          doc_type="twitter",
              body=json_data,
      ignore=400
          )

   streamer = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth, listener=StreamApi(), timeout=30)

    terms = ['#assange', 'assange']

    streamer.filter(None,terms)
```

Comment: Are documents getting correctly inserted on `twitter_stream` without any custom mapping?  If yes, how is the format of your "supposed" `date` field (the one that is not being recognized as a `date` field)?

Comment: yes, without any mapping the docs are inserted correctly. The format of the date field in tweets is "Sat Oct 11 22:14:45 +0000 2014"

Answer (score 0):

After reading the date field comment, that date format of the tweets **is not** one of the [default formats supported](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html).

For ElasticSearch to understand that as a date field you should  specify a custom mapping for the `twitter_stream` index, where you tell what date format you are expecting for the tweets date field. The syntax that explains the customizable date formats is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

So, if you are using Elasticsearch 7.X, you can specify the custom format this way:

```
PUT twitter_stream
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "YOUR_TWEETS_DATE_FIELD": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "EEE LLL dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can copy and execute the above configuration to the Kibana dev tools console. Then, try running the pyhton script again.
To explain the letters used in the format:

```
E       day-of-week                 text              Tue; Tuesday; T
M/L     month-of-year               number/text       7; 07; Jul; July; J
d       day-of-month                number            10
H       hour-of-day (0-23)          number            0
m       minute-of-hour              number            30
s       second-of-minute            number            55
Z       zone-offset                 offset-Z          +0000; -0800; -08:00;
y       year-of-era                 year              2004; 04
```

Also, there is no need to define anything else in the mapping. ElasticSearch will define the rest of the fields and types with its dynamic mapping.

Comment: thank you. I am still on 6.7.1. Could you please help with the code? very grateful :)

Comment: In versions 6.x you have to put the [doc_type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/mapping.html#mapping-type) of the index, yours being `doc_type=twitter`.  Specify the mapping like this:
`PUT twitter_stream
{
  "mappings": {
    "twitter":{
     "properties": {
      "YOUR_TWEETS_DATE_FIELD": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "EEE LLL dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
      }
    }
   }
  }
}`